# Present viewController over rootViewController when a notification is tapped

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller

When the app is in terminate state and I receive a push notification. Which if I view I want the app to load normally but it should present a `viewController` over the `rootViewController` for which I've added a close button and whenever i will tap this button i want simply dismiss this `viewController`.

In the method which is called when I open the app from notification I've done this:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    apptVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as! NotificationsViewController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController?.present(apptVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
completionHandler()
    }
}
```

But unfortunately when I do that the app crashes. I've implemented push notification using `firebase`. I want the app to run normally like it does it's just like presenting a view controller over the root view controller on launch when user is coming from notification.

**UPDATE**
here is the screenshot of my storyboard:
[image]

Comment: An error message from the crash would be helpful.  Your storyboard and `makeKeyAndVisible` code shouldn't appear here.  If anywhere it should be in `didFinishLaunching`.  You only need the last line of code in this function.

Comment: @Joe I've added the code as you suggested but it's still the same and how can I print the error as the app is in terminate state and there is no way the xCode can print the error as it is not running from there.

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha This is completely wrong! You'll need a delegate method only not the launch options

Comment: @Mannopson not sure what you mean there. Can you provide a code sample in the answer.

Comment: Here the what I meant! If you want to present a view controller when the notification is tapped? You'll need a `didReceive` method which is the delegate method of `UNUserNotificationDelegate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you'll need to insatiate tab bar controller first:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
```

And insatiate all of the `UINavigationControllers` with the your desired view controller:

```
let firstNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewiController(withIdentifier: "YourFirstNavigationController") as! UINavigationController

let NotificationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as! NotificationsViewController
```

And make them all as `viewControllers` of tab bar controller:

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [firstNavigationController]
```

Which is the navigation controller should be present this view controller? For example:

```
tabBarController.selectedViewController == firstNavigationController {
    firstNavigationController.present(NotificationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

It's a last thing:

```
self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**Note** It's just recommendation and therefore I have used one `UNavigationController`

So I have created a function called `present()`.

```
func present() {

let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourTabBarController") as! UITabBarController
let firstNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewiController(withIdentifier: "YourFirstNavigationController") as! UINavigationController
let NotificationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as! NotificationsViewController

tabBarController.viewControllers = [firstNavigationController]

tabBarController.selectedViewController == firstNavigationController {
        firstNavigationController.present(NotificationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }

self.window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)   
self.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


    }
}
```

But it's not useful even I think this is useless. We'll need an action whenever notification is tapped. And we should check an action `identifier` like this:

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        switch response.actionIdentifier {
        case UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier:
            self.present()
            completionHandler()

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your rootView Controller is nil. Try setting a rootview_Controller before presenting class even though you may have specified a rootviewController in did finish launnch of appDelegate.

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
 viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourRootVC") as UIViewController
 self.window?.rootViewController = viewController

 window?.rootViewController?.present(yourPusHNotificationVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    completionHandler()
        }
    }
```

Comment: my root view controller is a tabbar controller. So should I make a class for that?

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha Make your tab bar controller as a `rootViewController`.

Comment: @Mannopson please see my updated question I've done as Jeeson_7 mentioned but the result is still the same.

Comment: @ChaudhryTalha Your Tab bar controller's `viewControllers` are embedded in to the `UINavigationController`?

Comment: @Mannopson updated my question with the screenshot you can see the hierarchy of storyboards.